# Route page to url without extra suffix in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, view, routes

I want the default route to route to a specific view file.
But I don't want to have the name of that view file show up in the url.
if i go to domain.com, that's the view I want to see.

I want  the effects of having a public/index file, except that file is a view in the app/views/ folder , rather than in the public folder

Comment: define that as your root in routes. i am not sure what your expected resut may be render 'filename will work'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your routes file, you can do:

```
root 'controller#action'
```

That will call that controller action, then (by default) render the view related to that controller action.